Hashtag notation in Finite groups by D Gorenstein
My question is what the hashtag superscript notation means in finite groups by Daniel Gorenstein. It is for example is used in theorem 4.6 on page 139. From context I guess that it is the union of the conjugates of a set, by didn't manage to find the definition.
Any help would be appreciated.

Please try to make your questions self contained.

@Shaun Is there a way to include pictures on math stackexchange, or do you want me to make it self-contained in another way?

You could use MathJax and Detexify if you can.  Otherwise, click the link that looks like a picture in the edit box and upload.  It'll say you can't but keep going. It'll produce a link to the image that an experienced user like me can then covert into an image for you.

Try to reproduce it using MathJax. Does it look something like $A^#$? Also, the notation should be explained in the book somewhere.

Most good textbooks will have either a symbol index, or a section of "notation and terminology", or both. Gorenstein has both. While the symbol index isn't great, and fails to include this one, this particular symbol is defined in the third sentence of the "Notation and Terminology" section. You really should try to spend at least a couple of minutes searching on your own before asking people to do the searches for you.

It's defined on page 4: $G^\#$ is the set of non-identity elements of $G$.

In W. R.Scott's Group Theory (Dover, 1987) there is a notation index at the end, where $G^{\#}$ is listed as meaning $G$ without its identity element.
